# netcat is unable to establish communication

Tags: 18.04, irc, netcat

I followed the standard procedure to connect via an access port, based on the following commands:

```
nc -l -pxxxx

nc <ip address> -pxxxx
```

However when I enter the second command on another terminal no connection happens, and I just get:

> aOpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.187-1ubuntu0.1)
>   usage: nc [-46CDdFhklNnrStUuvZz] [-I length] [-i interval] [-M ttl]
>             [-m minttl] [-O length] [-P proxy_username] [-p source_port]
>             [-q seconds] [-s source] [-T keyword] [-V rtable] [-W recvlimit] [-w timeout]
>             [-X proxy_protocol] [-x proxy_address[:port]]           [destination] [port]

Answer (score 1):

The reason was so simple. The second command should not contain -p.

Comment: My bad everyone :)

Comment: **Attention LQ reviewers:** *Self-answer!* VTC Q instead of A!